# Dynamically Views on tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xamarin

I want to add a number (x) of uiLabels within a cell.

The problem is that these labels are duplicated me in all other cells.

Any idea how to resolve that problem ?

Comment: you need to use CustomCell. https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722.  check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're properly reusing the cells. Here is the standard implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // attempt to dequeue a cell to reuse
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCell"];

    // if there were none available to reuse, create one
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"YourCell"];
    }

    // now customize your cell based on your data source, in this case an array with dictionaries
    NSDictionary *dictionaryForIndex = self.myDataSource[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = dictionaryForIndex[@"title"];

    return cell;
}
```